# Access SQL subquery access field from parent

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a SQL query that works in Access 2016:

```
SELECT
    Count(*) AS total_tests,
    Sum(IIf(score>=securing_threshold And score<mastering_threshold,1,0)) AS total_securing,
    Sum(IIf(score>=mastering_threshold,1,0)) AS total_mastering,
    total_securing/Count(*) AS percent_securing,
    total_mastering/Count(*) AS percent_mastering,
    (Count(*)-total_securing-total_mastering)/Count(*) AS percent_below,
    subjects.subject,
    students.year_entered,
    IIf(Month(Date())<9,Year(Date())-students.year_entered+6,Year(Date())-students.year_entered+7) AS current_form,
    groups.group

FROM
    ((subjects
        INNER JOIN tests ON subjects.ID = tests.subject)
            INNER JOIN (students
                INNER JOIN test_results ON students.ID =   test_results.student) ON tests.ID = test_results.test)
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT *  FROM group_membership LEFT JOIN groups ON group_membership.group = groups.ID) As g
    ON students.ID = g.student

GROUP BY subjects.subject, students.year_entered, groups.group;
```

However, I wish to filter out irrelevant groups before joining them to my table. The table `groups` has a column `subject` which is a foreign key.

When I try changing `ON students.ID = g.student` to `ON students.ID = g.student And subjects.ID = g.subject` I get the error 'JOIN expression not supported'.

Alternatively, when I try adding `WHERE subjects.ID = groups.subject` to the subquery, it asks me for the parameter value of subjects.ID, although it is a column in the parent query.

Googling reveals many similar errors but they were all resolved by changing the brackets. That didn't help.

Just in case the table relationships help:

[image: table relationships]

Thank you.

EDIT: Sample database at https://www.dropbox.com/s/yh80oooem6gsni7/student%20tracker.ACCDB?dl=0

Comment: Please describe from what tables/fields this entails: *I wish to filter out irrelevant groups before joining them to my table*

Comment: I wish to filter out records from the table `groups`. In hindsight I chose a confusing name.

Comment: Students can be members of multiple `groups`s, but they will only be members of one `group` per subject. As the sql later groups by `group`, if a student is a member of multiple `group`s there will be some double counting. I intended to filter out `group`s that refer to different subjects.

Comment: You might need parentheses around the combined join expression: `ON (students.ID = g.student And subjects.ID = g.subject)`

Comment: Google found many people who solved it that way - but it made no difference here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by (a lot of trial and error and) taking the advice here to make queries in the GUI and joining them. The end result is 4 queries deep! If the database was bigger, performance would be awful... but now its working I can tweak it eventually.

Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the database to test, but I would use ***subject*** table as subquery:

(SELECT * FROM subject WHERE ***filter out what you don't need***) *Subj*

Then INNER JOIN this new *Subj* Table in your query which would exclude irrelevant groups.

Also I would never create join in ***WHERE*** clause (*WHERE subjects.ID = groups.subject*), what this does it creates cartesian product (table with all the possible combinations of subjects.ID and groups.subject) then it filters out records to satisfy your join. When dealing with huge data it might take forever or crash.

Error related to "Join expression may not be supported"; do datatypes match in those fields?

Comment: I would like the final output to include *all* subjects (`subject` is one of the grouping variables) but for each subject I only want appropriate `groups` to be joined.

Comment: As for datatypes, they are all Numbers (Long Integers).

Comment: In that case I would use subject table twice, you can join the second subject subquery with those groups (which would filter out those records).

Answer (score 1):

MS Access queries with many joins are difficult to update by SQL alone as parenetheses pairings are required unlike other RDBMS's and these pairings must follow an order. Moreover, some pairings can even be nested. Hence, for beginners it is advised to build queries with complex and many joins using the query design GUI in the MS Office application and let it build out the SQL.

For a simple filter on the `g` derived table, you could filter *subject* on the derived table, `g`, but likely you want want all *subjects*:

```
...
(SELECT * FROM group_membership 
 LEFT JOIN groups ON group_membership.group = groups.ID
 WHERE groups.subject='Earth Science') As g
...
```

So for all *subjects*, consider re-building query from scratch in GUI that nearly mirrors your table relationships which actually auto-links joins in the GUI. Then, drop unneeded tables.

1. Usually you want to begin with the join table or set like *groups* and *group_membership* or *tests* and *test_results*. In fact, consider saving the `g` derived table as its own query.
2. Then add the distinct record primary source tables like *students* and *subjects*.
3. You may even need to play around with order in `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses to attain desired results, and maybe even add the same table in query. And be careful with adding join tables like `group_membership` (two one-to-many links),  to `GROUP BY` queries as it leads to the duplicate record aggregation. So you may need to join aggregates queries by subject.

Unless you can post content of all tables, from our perspective it is difficult to help from here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am beginning to realise you are right. I will either have to manipulate the GUI into this, or get the user to run this query on one subject at a time.

Comment: Dropbox/GoogleDrive/OneDrive us a link to a stripped down version of database, remove private info or delete all data but keep table relationships.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yh80oooem6gsni7/student%20tracker.ACCDB?dl=0 Thank you. The query is the only one in the database.

Comment: I solved it by making several queries in the GUI and joining them in stages. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent! As I thought, return to the query design to set up relationships and then join queries (instead of tables) as needed. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery `g` uses a LEFT JOIN, but there is a enforced 1:n relation between the two tables, so there will always be a matching group. Use a INNER JOIN instead.

With `g.subject` you are trying to join on a column that is on the right side of a left join, that cannot really work.

Also you shouldn't use `SELECT *` on a join of tables with identical column names. Include only the qualified column names that you need.

```
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT group_membership.student, groups.group, groups.subject
     FROM group_membership INNER JOIN groups 
       ON group_membership.group = groups.ID) As g
ON (students.ID = g.student AND subjects.ID = g.subject)
```

I would call the columns in group_membership `group_ID` and `student_ID` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Annoyingly, it gives the same error 'JOIN expression not supported' and highlights `students.ID = g.student AND subjects.ID = g.subject`.

Comment: Just as an experiment, what happens if you change the above LEFT JOIN to a INNER JOIN too?